# how to create a screen you can't exit in C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, windows-10

I'm trying to create a screen that would pop up that would stop the user from doing anything on the screen, I want it so the user can only type in the box provided and they can't press any other key to exit the screen (like win R, alt f4, ....), any Ideas on what I can do here? thank you.

Comment: also make it so the user can't open task manager or be able to kill the task

Comment: you may use modal forms https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you trying to make a dedicated kiosk type application or something that runs alongside, er, over other applications?

Comment: Ignoring the "how", *why* would one do this to the user? It sounds like malware.

Comment: Even if you manage to block those key combinations you'll never be able to prevent the user from pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del as it's hard-coded into the operating system.

Comment: @stealththeninja actually the opposite, Its a security software :)

Comment: @AdamG its like a lock so unwanted users can't do anything without the password

Comment: @rockstar thank you, ill check it out and get back to you :)

Comment: modal forms aren't going to help you. There are already group policy rules that can be set to lock an idle machine, but why not just programmatically lock the workstation?

Comment: @AdamG I don't know how to do that, ill do some research

Comment: @TheGeneral yeah I know, but the other way seems impossible, I been searching for a solution for a month now and I can't find a way so I thought of a different way

Comment: It sounds like the start of an [arms race](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120117-00/?p=8523). Raymond Chen has written a lot about these sorts of scenarios. Sooner or later, you have to declare that either a user can *always* beat the program or a program can *always* beat the user. Microsoft, not unreasonably, has come down on the side of "user".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do to prevent all the ways of killing a task. If you were creating a Kiosk style application, you can replace explorer.exe and use a custom shell that you write. Exiting your application then immediately logs off, but you still need to handle things like task manager. But in your case, you want to share the desktop with other users. I think the easiest way is to lock the workstation programmatically

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
```

Then call `LockWorkStation();` when you have occasion to do so. Let the OS handle the blocking of the user operations.

Comment: I tried the method, but I need the user to be locked in the application, and be able to type in the password before being locked out

Comment: What you are describing is a pretty classic XY problem. I asked earlier whether you had a kiosk type application, which would be a typical reason to prevent exit. Your answer indicated that you wanted to lock them out of other applications without the password, but you haven't indicated how immediately locking the PC fails to achieve this. Describe your threat model.